# Spring Data Neo4j Ridiculously Slow Over Rest

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

```
     public List<Errand> interestFeed(Person person, int skip, int limit)
        throws ControllerException {

    person = validatePerson(person);
    String query = String
            .format("START n=node:ErrandLocation('withinDistance:[%.2f, %.2f, %.2f]') RETURN n  ORDER BY n.added DESC SKIP %s LIMIT %S",
                    person.getLongitude(), person.getLatitude(),
                    person.getWidth(), skip, limit);
    String queryFast = String
            .format("START n=node:ErrandLocation('withinDistance:[%.2f, %.2f, %.2f]') RETURN n SKIP %s LIMIT %S",
                    person.getLongitude(), person.getLatitude(),
                    person.getWidth(), skip, limit);
    Set<Errand> errands = new TreeSet<Errand>();
    System.out.println(queryFast);

    Result<Map<String, Object>> results = template.query(queryFast, null);


    Iterator<Errand> objects = results.to(Errand.class).iterator();
    return copyIterator (objects);
}

public List<Errand> copyIterator(Iterator<Errand> iter) {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Double startD = start.doubleValue();
    List<Errand> copy = new ArrayList<Errand>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Errand e = iter.next();
        copy.add(e);
        System.out.println(e.getType());
    }
    Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Double endD = end.doubleValue();
    p ((endD - startD)/1000);
    return copy;
}
```

When I profile the copyIterator function it takes about 6 seconds to fetch just 10 results. I use Spring Data Neo4j Rest to connect with a Neo4j server running on my local machine. I even put a print function to see how fast the iterator is converted to a list and it does appear slow. Does each iterator.next() make a new Http call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Errand is a node entity then yes, spring-data-neo4j will make a http call for each entity to fetch all its labels (it's fault of neo4j, which doesn't return labels when you return whole node in cypher).

You can enable debug level logging in `org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestCypherQueryEngine` to log all cypher statements going to neo4j.

To avoid this call use `@QueryResult` http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_mapresult

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but to mark it, I use the neo4jtemplate.query() function because the spatial query does not support parameters. So how do I map results using the @QueryResult template.query(queryFast, null);